# Explain i2cdetect tool MODE_AUTO logic

Tags: c, linux, i2c

i2cdetect in [i2c-tools](https://i2c.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/I2C_Tools) use different methods to probe devices.

```c
case MODE_AUTO:
                if ((i+j >= 0x30 && i+j <= 0x37)
                 || (i+j >= 0x50 && i+j <= 0x5F))
                    cmd = MODE_READ;
                else
                    cmd = MODE_QUICK;
                break;
            }
```

Do addresses range in 0x30~0x37 and 0x50~0x5F have special meaning?

Comment: Yes. These are often the page accessible EEPROMs. That's why the method is different. https://rohmfs-rohm-com-cn.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/memory/eeprom/eep_i2c_address_page_opcode_an-e.pdf.

Comment: Here is more info: https://docs.kernel.org/misc-devices/eeprom.html